# How does mySql database connection really work?

Tags: mysql

So whenever I make a connection to mySQL in javaFX I usually write something like this:
`String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + dbName;`

My question is how does the connection stays active if I move the app from one device to another?

I tried moving the app form my PC to my Laptop and it didn't connect, I also have the mySQL connector in the app's library.

I know this is probably a noob-ish question about how mySQL connections work but I couldn't really find anything on it.

Comment: I am no expert, but I believe localhost means your database is on that machine. So if you move the program to a new machine and do not move or copy the database to that machine, then there is nothing to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

The connection to database is a persistent physical connections. In the real life you will install the database and the clients (Java FX) in different machines, so you will have something like this:

- Machine A

  - Mysql Database
  - IP: 192.168.0.100
- Machine B

  - Desktop PC with Java FX
  - IP: 192.168.0.110
- Machine C

  - Laptop PC with Java FX
  - IP: 192.168.0.120

In order to connect from machine B and C to Mysql database you need to configure the Jdbc string connection to `url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.100/" + dbName;`

Remember that `localhost` means: `THIS MACHINE` so if you put `localhost` in connection string, JavaFX will try to connect to a database in the same machine where it is running.